# JSON Object is null while parsing

Tags: java, android, json, gson

The format of my json object is:

```
   String jsonObjRecv =  {
      "response":{
       "respobj":{
        "id":<int>,
        "number":<string>,
        "validated":<boolean>
         }
        },
        "status":"ok",
        "errors":null
        }
```

It works when code is:

```
        JSONObject jsonObjCont = new JSONObject(jsonObjRecv);
        String getString= jsonObjCont.toString(2);
```

In this case getString != null and I can receive data, but when I try to get nested data of JSON object as like:

```
        JSONObject jsonObjCont = new JSONObject(jsonObjRecv);
        JSONObject regNumber = jsonObjCont.getJSONObject("respobj");
        String number= regNumber.getString("number");
```

it dont work.

I tried to use GSON library, but it works when:

```
public String parse(String jsonObjRecv) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonObjRecv);
    String result = jelement.toString();
    return result;
```

and don't work :

```
public String parse(String jsonObjRecv) {
    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonObjRecv);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("respobj");

    String result = jobject.get("number").toString();
    return result;
```

Where is my mistake?

Comment: When you say it does not work, what happens? Do you get an exception or unexpected output?
http://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/tags/1.1.1/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/JsonElement.html

Comment: Can you show the _real_ JSON input?

Comment: @AnuragKapur - you just linked to an *ancient* version of `Gson`

Comment: @AnuragKapur what's the difference – the same result...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you're not accessing your JSON object correctly - it's an object that contains a `response` object which contains a `respobj` object.

`Gson` example follows. Note the comment in the code - you need to get the `response` object *then* get the `respobj` from it.

```
public static void main( String[] args )
{
    String jsonObjRecv =  "{\"response\":{\"respobj\":{\"id\":1,\"number\":\"22\",\"validated\":true}},\"status\":\"ok\",\"errors\":null}";

    JsonElement jelement = new JsonParser().parse(jsonObjRecv);
    JsonObject jobject = jelement.getAsJsonObject();

    // Here is where you're making an error. You need to get the outer
    // 'response' object first, then get 'respobj' from that.
    jobject = jobject.getAsJsonObject("response").getAsJsonObject("respobj");

    String result = jobject.get("number").getAsString();

    System.out.println(result);

}
```

Output:

> 22

**Edit to add:** Note I used `getAsString()` vs. `toString()` - if you use the latter you get the raw JSON which will incluse the quotes around the value (e.g. the output would be `"22"`)